# iPhone app saving state - nsmutableindexset and nsuintegers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, savestate

I'm newer to Xcode development and am trying to save the state of my app which tracks multiple index sets, integers and strings. I've tried a lot of different code and haven't been able to get it to work saving to a .plist. What is the best approach for saving the following data types,  `NSMutableIndexSets` and `NSUIntegers`? Any direction would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you can't save index sets to a plist, or to user defaults. There is a very short list of object types that you can write to a plist. Look up the docs on the NSDictionary class in Xcode, and search for the string "property list object" That's where they tell you which objects can be written to a properly list. The object types are NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects.

Omar Abdelhafith posted a very long and complex block of code to convert an index set to an array, which should work.

There is a much simpler way however. NSIndexSet conforms to the NSCoding protocol, which means that you can convert it to NSData with a single call:

```
NSData *setData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: mySet];
```

And to turn it back into an index set:

```
NSIndexSet *setFromData= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: setData];
NSMutableIndexSet *mutableSet = [setFromData mutableCopy];
```

Note that with all of these approaches, if you start with a mutable object (set, array, dictionary, etc) then when you read it back, the object you get back will be an immutable version. You have to manually convert it to a mutable version. Most objects that have a mutable variant support the method mutableCopy.

Comment: This worked and did cut down on the code required. Thanks, Duncan.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
//Saving
NSMutableIndexSet *set = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

[set addIndex:1];
[set addIndex:2];

NSMutableArray *arrToSave = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSUInteger currentIndex = [set firstIndex];
while (currentIndex != NSNotFound)
{
    [arrToSave addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentIndex]];
    currentIndex = [set indexGreaterThanIndex:currentIndex];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSUInteger integer = 100;
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/savePath.txt"];

[dic setValue:arrToSave forKey:@"set"];
[dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:integer] forKey:@"int"];
[dic writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];



//Loading
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/savePath.txt"];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:savePath];

NSArray *arr = [dic valueForKey:@"set"];
NSMutableIndexSet *set = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
[set addIndex:[[arr objectAtIndex:0] unsignedIntValue]];
[set addIndex:[[arr objectAtIndex:1] unsignedIntValue]];
NSUInteger integer = [[dic valueForKey:@"int"] unsignedIntValue];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for a set but how do I change the code to use an nsmutableindexset? This is the line I'm not sure how to convert,[dic setValue:[set allObjects] forKey:@"set"];?  If I change 'set' to my nsmutableindexset, I get

Comment: I get an error 'Arc issue, no visible @interface for nsmutableindexset' declares the selector allObjects'. Thanks for the help Omar. Any ideas on converting this line for an indexset?

Comment: This works for the index set now. Thanks, Omar!

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know there is a set list of items you can archive to a plist file.
From memory (which means you should go look it up in the docs) it's NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSData, NSNumber and... a couple of others that i can't remember. THe point is your index set probably isn't one of them so you'll need to convert it to something else, archive it and on wake unarchive it and reconvert back.